# SQL Server : Create role and adding table permissions to the role

Tags: sql-server, select, roles, sql-grant

I am trying to give someone access to the some of the view. Below is the stored procedure I am using

```
/*Create role*/
CREATE ROLE DBandBI_Testers_Role;
GO

/*Grant select on all views in dbo*/
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(3000)
DECLARE @RoleName NVARCHAR(100) = 'DBandBI_Testers_Role';

DECLARE GrantExec_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON a.test1 TO [' + @RoleName + '];
            GRANT SELECT ON a.test2 TO [' + @RoleName + ']; 
            GRANT SELECT ON a.test3 TO [' + @RoleName + '];  ' AS SQLstatement
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

OPEN GrantExec_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM GrantExec_Cursor INTO @SQL

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN --Grant Permissions
   EXEC(@SQL)

   FETCH NEXT FROM GrantExec_Cursor INTO @SQL
END --Grant Permissions

CLOSE GrantExec_Cursor
DEALLOCATE GrantExec_Cursor
GO
```

I want to Grant select on multiple tables (test1, test2, test3) in the stored procedure and I think I am not using the right syntax to perform it.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention you want to grant permissions for tables when an SP is called.  Did you grant EXECUTE permissions to the ROLE/users to the SP itself?  I think I remember (not sure when using roles, but for using IDs) if you grant execute to the SP, they inherit the select permissions from all the tables in the SP.  Same applies for inserts/updates as well.  If you grant execute to the SP the objects inside inherit the permissions that the SP has (with some exceptions).  Did you try that?

Comment: Basically the only problem I am having in the above SP is that when I trying to assign GRANT SELECT permissions to the Role.

    DECLARE GrantExec_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON a.test1 TO [' + @RoleName + '];' AS SQLstatement
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

If I run the SP with this statement it works fine. but with multiple tables it is giving me error.

Comment: Never mind. It got resolved. I was incorrectly typing the table name.Thanks Brad!